# Авторизация ssh по сертификату 1 ip адрес несколько виртуальных хостов

Tags: ssh

Как авторизоваться по ключу и как отправить его на удаленных хост с нестандартным портом я знаю, но вот не понимаю как можно на хостовую машину и на виртуалки скопировать ключ чтобы, так как там ip адрес один, а машины разные.
Подскажите рецепт

Comment: значит эти виртуалки на основной хост машине должны разводится по разным портам

Comment: @Mike так они и так разводятся

Comment: ключ скопировать - `ssh-copy-id -p <port> <host> ключ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у программы *ssh-copy-id* есть точно такая же опция `-p порт`, как и у программы *ssh*. служит она для указания порта, к которому надо подключаться.

скопируйте публичный ключ:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -p порт пользователь@машина
```

и подключайтесь после этого без ввода пароля:

```
$ ssh -p порт пользователь@машина
```